# Using pipe/dup2 to communicate with a Python subprocess

Tags: c, posix, dup2

I'd like to use Python to implement a user interface for my C program.  However, I can't seem to get communication working.  Here's what I've done so far, `test.c`:

```
int main()
{
    int pipe_in[2], pipe_out[2];
    if (pipe(pipe_in) != 0 || pipe(pipe_out) != 0)
    {
        perror("pipe");
    return 1;
    }

    int _proc_handle = 0;
    if ((_proc_handle=fork()) == 0)
    {
        printf("Starting up Python interface...\n");
        dup2(pipe_in[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pipe_out[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipe_in[0]);
        close(pipe_out[1]);
        execlp("python", "python", "interface.py", (char*)NULL);
        perror("execlp");
        printf("Error executing Python.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    _write_fd = pipe_in[1];
    _read_fd = pipe_out[0];

    sleep(1);
    char buffer[256];
    int n = read(_read_fd, buffer, 11);

    printf("n: %d\n", n);
    printf("buffer: `%s'\n", buffer);
    write(_write_fd, "from C\n", 5);

    return 0;
}
```

and `interface.py` is:

```
import sys
import time

time.sleep(0.1)
print >>sys.stdout, 'from python'
print >>sys.stderr, sys.stdin.readline()
```

Running this, I expected it to print,

```
Starting up Python interface...
n: 11
buffer: `from python'
from C
```

But instead, it simply hangs after,

```
Starting up Python interface...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your python script:

```
sys.stdout.flush() # after printing to stdout
sys.stderr.flush() # after printing to stderr
```

(Line buffering is the default for tty devices, but not for pipes).

In the future you'll want to detect EOF on your pipes in the parent process (and/or in the child), and you'll have to close unused ends of your pipes in parent, too. EDIT: And to close *other* unused ends of your pipes in a child process.

```
/* This should be in parent as well */
close(pipe_in[0]);
close(pipe_out[1]);

/* This should be added to the child */
close(pipe_in[1]);
close(pipe_out[0]);
```

Comment: Aargh I can't believe it was just an unflushed buffer.  Thank you!  That totally worked.

Comment: Is there any way to tell Python not to buffer the standard output?

Comment: @Steve start it with `python -u` (it disables stdin, stdout, stderr buffering entirely)